# apply function or loop within mutate

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply

Let's say I have a data frame. I would like to mutate new columns by subtracting each pair of the existing columns. There are rules in the matching columns. For example, in the below codes, the prefix is all same for the first component (base_g00) of the subtraction and the same for the second component (allow_m00). Also, the first component has numbers from 27 to 43 for the id and the second component's id is from 20 to 36 also can be interpreted as (1st_id-7). I am wondering for the following code, can I write in a **apply function or loops within mutate** format to make the codes simpler. Thanks so much for any suggestions in advance!

```
pred_error<-y07_13%>%mutate(annual_util_1=base_g0027-allow_m0020,
     annual_util_2=base_g0028-allow_m0021,
     annual_util_3=base_g0029-allow_m0022,
     annual_util_4=base_g0030-allow_m0023,
     annual_util_5=base_g0031-allow_m0024,
     annual_util_6=base_g0032-allow_m0025,
     annual_util_7=base_g0033-allow_m0026,
     annual_util_8=base_g0034-allow_m0027,
     annual_util_9=base_g0035-allow_m0028,
     annual_util_10=base_g0036-allow_m0029,
     annual_util_11=base_g0037-allow_m0030,
     annual_util_12=base_g0038-allow_m0031,
     annual_util_13=base_g0039-allow_m0032,
     annual_util_14=base_g0040-allow_m0033,
     annual_util_15=base_g0041-allow_m0034,
     annual_util_16=base_g0042-allow_m0035,
     annual_util_17=base_g0043-allow_m0036)
```

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data to test solutions on. We don't need much, 2 or 3 rows, 2 or 3 column pairs would be plenty. `dput()` is a great way to make a copy/pasteable version of data you have, including all class and structure information. `dput(y07_13[1:4, c("base_g0027", "allow_m0020", "base_g0028", "allow_m0021")])` would be perfect to share the first 4 rows of the first 2 column pairs.

Comment: Thanks Gregor for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think a more idiomatic tidyverse approach would be to reshape your data so those column groups are encoded as a variable instead of as separate columns which have the same semantic meaning.

For instance,

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(stringr)       
y07_13 <- tibble(allow_m0021 = 1:5,
                 allow_m0022 = 2:6,
                 allow_m0023 = 11:15,
                 base_g0028 = 5,
                 base_g0029 = 3:7,
                 base_g0030 = 100)

y07_13 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(name, "allow_m|base_g"),
         num = str_remove(name, type) %>% as.numeric(),
         group = num - if_else(type == "allow_m", 20, 27)) %>%
  select(row, type, group, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(annual_util = base_g - allow_m)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
     row group allow_m base_g annual_util
   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1     1       1      5           4
 2     1     2       2      3           1
 3     1     3      11    100          89
 4     2     1       2      5           3
 5     2     2       3      4           1
 6     2     3      12    100          88
 7     3     1       3      5           2
 8     3     2       4      5           1
 9     3     3      13    100          87
10     4     1       4      5           1
11     4     2       5      6           1
12     4     3      14    100          86
13     5     1       5      5           0
14     5     2       6      7           1
15     5     3      15    100          85
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks Jon!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is vectorised base R approach -

```
base_cols <- paste0("base_g00", 27:43)
allow_cols <- paste0("allow_m00", 20:36)
new_cols <- paste0("annual_util", 1:17)
y07_13[new_cols] <- y07_13[base_cols] - y07_13[allow_cols]
y07_13
```

Comment: This is very clever! Thanks Ronak!